# What is a faster and more Pythonic way to read the CSV and make a data frame from it?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

**Input**: A CSV with 50,000 rows; each row containing 910 columns of value 0/1.
**Output**: A data frame to run my CNN on.

I wrote a code that reads the CSV line by line. For each line, I split the data into 2 parts, called **neurons** (900 columns) and **labels** (10 columns). Since these are lists, I convert them to Numpy arrays. As I go to the next line, I do the same thing and stack the arrays to eventually get 4 conventional datasets:
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test

My code is working because I tested it on a small CSV with just 6 rows. But it is taking forever when I run it on the actual dataset of 50,000 rows, after the array initialization, to convert the rows to a data frame.

So I was wondering if there is a faster way to go about with this conversion, or is it okay to just wait here!

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Read the dataset from the CSV file into a dataframe
df = pd.read_csv("bci_dataset_labelled.csv")

start_init = time.time()

xvalues = np.zeros((900,), dtype=np.int)
yvalues = np.zeros((10,), dtype=np.int)

print("--- Arrays initialized in %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_init))

start_conversion = time.time()

for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
    # separate the neurons from the labels
    x = list(row[:900])
    y = list(row[900:])

    # convert the lists to numpy arrays
    x = np.array(x) 
    y = np.array(y)

    xvalues = np.vstack((xvalues, x))
    yvalues = np.vstack((yvalues, y))

print("--- CSV rows converted to dataframe in %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_conversion))

start_split = time.time()

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(xvalues, yvalues, test_size=0.2)

print("--- Dataframe split into training and testing datasets in %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_split))

num_classes = y_test.shape[1]
num_neurons = x_train[0].shape[0]

# define baseline model
def baseline_model():
    #create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(
        num_neurons, 
        input_dim = num_neurons,
        kernel_initializer = 'normal',
        activation = 'relu'
    ))
    model.add(Dense(
        num_classes,
        kernel_initializer = 'normal',
        activation = 'softmax'
        ))
    #compile model
    model.compile(
        loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
        optimizer = 'adam',
        metrics = ['accuracy'])
    return model

# build the model
model = baseline_model()

# fit the model
model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data = (x_test, y_test),
    epochs = 10, batch_size = 200, verbose = 2)

# final evaluation of the model
scores = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Baseline error: %0.2f%%" % (100-scores[1]*100))
```

It is just stuck here:

```
Rachayitas-MacBook-Pro:bci_hp rachayitagiri$ python3 binarycnn.py 
Using TensorFlow backend.
--- Arrays initialized in 2.4080276489257812e-05 seconds ---
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated! Thank you!

Edit: Putting the output as text from the console, instead of the picture. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: don't post pictures. if you post pictures - don't post white nothingness... copying and pasting your consols output would have been as beneficial ...

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to read the first dataframe line by line when you could split the columns apart into two dataframes directly

Comment: read all of into pandas and then start splitting it up? never do line by line stuff

Comment: I actually used your suggestions. The code is much faster and shorter now. Performed the train/test split first, followed by slicing out the required datasets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see, your problem is not with the `read_csv` function, but with the way you extract the information from the DataFrame. You could get `xvalues` and `yvalues` directly from the DataFrame, instead of reading your DataFrame line after line, which is very costly. DataFrames allow you to do that in a quite optimized way.

From what I understood your X values are in the 900 first columns and the Y values are after that. Here's how I would go about it :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time


start_init = time.time()
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(50000, 910)))
print("--- DataFrame initialized in %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_init))

start_conversion = time.time()

x = df.loc[:, :900] # Here's where you get your x values, 900 first values in each row
y = df.loc[:, 900:] # And here you retrieve the y values

# All that's left is to convert that to a numpy array by doing this 
xvalues = x.values
yvalues = y.values

print("--- Took data out of DataFrame in %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - 
start_conversion))
print(x.shape, y.shape)
```

I get the following prints for this code :

```
--- Arrays initialized in 0.6232161521911621 seconds ---
--- Took data out of DataFrame in 0.038640737533569336 seconds ---
(50000, 901) (50000, 10)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right! I actually did pretty much the same thing from the suggestions above. It was pointless to iterate over the data frame line by line when I could actually just use the splitting functions. My CNN is up and working now. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

You probably won't be able to beat [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), which is available out of the box and is probably better tested than any other solution out there.

Comment: Yes. Since it returns a data frame itself, I was unnecessarily reading it line by line. Using train_test_split(), followed by slicing using iloc gives a much shorter code and it runs faster too.